# Castalia Memory Issue

Tags: memory, omnet++

My application layer protocol works fine, but when the number of nodes is large (more than 600) it exits without any error.
I traced the code and didn't find any problem. It seems a memory problem since the number of nodes is large and doing many operations.

**Update:**

In my application:

- Each node broadcasts 2msg/second, during all the simulation time.
- The msgs contain much information related to my application.
- All the nodes are static.
- Using BypassRouting, BypassMAC, Radio cc2420.
- Castalia works for nodes larger than 600 and reaches to 2500 from my previous experiments but with low simulation time ... so it depends on the relation between the # of nodes and simulation time and # of sent messages per second.

**Single experiment run successfully**... but when running for example with 30 seed (i.e. -r 30) ... & num of nodes = 110

***its stopped after exp 13 simulation time = 1000s***

& ***its stopped after exp 22 if simulation time = 600s***

**How I can free memory from unnecessary things during simulation runs.**
(note: previously I increased the swap memory and worked for a specific limit)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information on your application and the simulation scenario it's hard to provide very specific suggestions. At the very least, you could provide your ini file and information about any custom modules you are using (your application module for example). Are you using any mobile nodes for example? Which protocols are you using? What does you app module do? In general Castalia should be able to handle 600 nodes. In the past, we have tested Castalia with thousands of (static) nodes.

You could use a memory profiler. An excellent tool (a suite of tools really) is `valgrind`. You can find memory leaks, and you can also memory profile your program. The heap profiler tool of valgrind is called 'massif':

> Massif is a heap profiler. It performs detailed heap profiling by taking regular snapshots of a program's heap. It produces a graph showing heap usage over time, including information about which parts of the program are responsible for the most memory allocations. The graph is supplemented by a text or HTML file that includes more information for determining where the most memory is being allocated. Massif runs programs about 20x slower than normal.

Read the [valgrind documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) for more info. This is the way you invoke the tool:

```
valgrind --tool=massif <executable> <arguments>
```

The executable in this case is `CastaliaBin` (not the `Castalia` python script, which is a higher level execution tool).

Comment: Thanks, Dr. I've updated the question with more info.

Comment: Thanks, using massif tool, I found the place of code that consumes the memory.